# HTML 'select' element cannot be resized using CSS's height

Tags: html, css

I wonder why CSS' height can't resize a 'select' element in HTML.

```
<select>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
</select>
```

and CSS:

```
select {
    height: 40px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It worked for me, in IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera

Comment: @tom agree, it worked for me as well

Comment: @vattanak please clear browser cache and try, Which browser and version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You should use line-height along with. Below fiddle shows you the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/pckh7spw/

```
select {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: It works without `line-height` i think he is trying to give height to the `option` http://jsfiddle.net/pckh7spw/1/

Comment: It is always better to have line-height for fixed height select boxes for cross-browser support. Any how it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

if any css overriding this class then use following class

```
select {
    height: 40px !important;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/qd2mvgk8/

```
<select>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
    <option>Five</option>  
</select>

select {
    height: 50px;
    border:1px solid #acacac;
    width:250px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color:#df781b;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

try this one, I did add some styling to it just so it might help you out.